# Will Ubuntu make use of PackageKit?

Tags: package-management, apt

The primary design goal of PackageKit is to unify all the software graphical tools used in different distributions. Has Ubuntu any plans for adoption?

Answer (score 5):

There is tentative agreement to move Ubuntu Software Center to PackageKit, it was in the news last week:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/cross-distro-unified-installer-is-on.html

Basically the plan is to unify the meta data for all installable packages, this way we can have a standard way of allowing all developers to put their most important data into the standard desktop files and not have to expect them to fill out debian and rpm package information. PackageKit is being used alongside a de-branded Ubuntu Software Center in a project called `AppStream`

As soon as the debian-packagekit integration is perfect, I'm sure Ubuntu can ship it.

Comment: Interesting.  Any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

I'll be working at PackageKit backend for Ubuntu Software Center, as a Google Summer of Code [this summer](http://swarm.cs.pub.ro/~alexef/gsoc/proposal.html). With a bit of luck, this can be done.